# Any game/graph theory on finite bipartite graph games with perfect information?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, game-theory

Suppose you have an undirected, bipartite graph, that consists of vertex sets *A* and *B*.

There are two players, *P1* and *P2*. *P1* may start, by picking any vertex *V* from *A*.
Then, *P2* will choose a vertex *W* in *B*, adjacent to *V*. *V* will be removed.
Now, *P1* can choose another vertex from *A*, adjacent to *W*, etc.
A player wins when he/she was the last one to pick a vertex.

This is a (graph?) game with perfect information. One of the two players will always have a winning strategy.

What existing game/graph theory can be applied, to find which player will win?

I'm trying to create an algorithm that will solve this problem as fast as possible!

I've found a lot of interesting papers on game and graph theory, but none explicitly covered this problem, or theory that can be applied to solve this problem (as far as I know).

Thanks a lot for your knowledge, time and help!

Comment: The game can be solved using [minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), or its variant: [alpha-beta pruning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha–beta_pruning). There may be more efficient solutions. What you're looking for is the root node of a tree where all leaf nodes are an even distance from the root.

Comment: I have looked into minimax and alpha-beta pruning, but I don't really know how I can apply those on a graph efficiently with over 1000 nodes in the graph..

Comment: A very closely related question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3532506/26369) on Math StackExchange.